# Azure AD implementation in WCF service build in .net 4.8

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement the Azure AD authentication in the WCF service build in .net 4.8.. i have gone through many link ..got few sample build in .net core but didn't get any proper example for WCf service. can any one guide me that is it possible in wcf service to secure it with Azure AD???

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this step and the link provided:

1. Create a new application service by publishing the data service application from Visual Studio.
2. Use the Express option to create a new AD application and configure Azure authentication for the application service.
3. Please note the client ID of the newly registered web application.
   Register native client applications in Active Directory and configure permissions for application services.
4. Configure the native client using the client ID of the Azure AD infrastructure, etc.
5. There is no need to perform any POST to successfully connect to the data service, that is, use the code posted at the beginning of this thread.
   https://jpda.dev/protecting-wcf-with-azure-ad-586487769b5e
   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1092557/WCF-Security-and-Authentication-in-Azure-WsHttpBin
   [Azure Active Directory and WCF authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930018/azure-active-directory-and-wcf-authentication) 
   [Azure Active Directory and WCF Service Library Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162398/azure-active-directory-and-wcf-service-library-example)

Comment: actually i want the user to enter his username and password in a react app .. react app send those credentials to WCF service and WCF service call the azure ad as rest api  and get those credentials verified and send the access token.. then i should be able to get claims from that token to get user credentials to move ahead... this is the scenario ...any comment ???

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the document to [obtain an Azure AD access token by username and password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token).